# Upload Apk failed to AppGallery Huawei

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I have been trying to upload a new update for my app in Huawei's AppGallery for 3 days but I still have the error: "Upload failed. Make sure that no proxy is used and your network is working."

My Apk file size is 27MB. I am not using a proxy and my internet is working fine but I still get this message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m50va.png)

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: Did you try a VPN?

Comment: did you drag and drop?

Comment: @null_override Not yet, but I will try with a VPN

Comment: @Antonio, Yes, drag and drop also doesn't work

Comment: @YassineRaffie Could you please leave your appId? Let me check the info to see the problem.

Comment: @shirley I tried again this morning and it worked, I didn't change anything. I think it was a bug in the AppGallery platform

Comment: @YassineRaffie All right. We will check this issue. If you have more questions. feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

That usually happens when you upload APK with poor or average internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me for at least 10 attempts. With and without VPN. With and without drag and drop. Surprisingly solved as soon as I deactivated the ad blocker.

Answer (score 0):

**Incognito Mode** works for me... Still doesn't know the root cause.